# Best way to create select_tag by cycling class

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this scenario:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many      :children,    :class_name => "Category",    :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  belongs_to    :parent,      :class_name => "Category",    :foreign_key => "parent_id"

  def self.for_select
    ?? DO SOMETHING ??
  end

end
```

And i simply need to  generate options for a `select_tag` like this:

```
Category 1
  - Subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2
  - Subcategory 3
Category 2
  - Subcategory 4
  - Subcategory 5
```

How can i do this without stressing the database with a cyclic query?

Actually, I have something like this, but it is performing too many queries:

```
def self.for_select
  ret = []
  Category.where(parent_id: nil).each do |m|
    ret << [m.name, m.id]
    m.children.each { |c| ret << ["- #{c.name}", c.id] }
  end
  return ret
end
```

Comment: You can eager load the children, to limit the number of db calls. `Category.where(parent_id: nil).includes(:children)`

Comment: @Santhosh is right. I'd add it as a `scope`...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you want to appear in the select options.  Here, i'm assuming that a "category" is all categories that don't have a parent, and the subcategories are the direct children of these.

in your category class

```
#class methods section
class << self

  def select_options
    top_level_categories = Category.where(:parent_id => nil).includes(:children)
    top_level_categories.collect{|category| [[category.name, category.id]] + category.children.collect{|category| [" - #{category.name}, category.id]}}
  end
```

which should return

```
[["Category 1", 321], [" - Subcategory 1", 123], [" - Subcategory 2", 456]...etc]
```

then, in your view, do

```
select_tag "foo", options_for_select(Category.select_options)
```

Comment: Are Category 1 and Category 2 not groups, then, in the options that you said you wanted?  I think your requirements are unclear.

Comment: @MattiaMalonni Have you tried what I suggested ? It will work, even I use it in my codebase...

Comment: o i c.  I'm rewriting my answer as this is confusing.  Also realised that you can't just get Category.all at the start

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
class Category
  # ...

  scope :main_categories, -> { where(parent_id: nil) }

  def self.for_select
    main_categories.includes(:children).each_with_object([]) do |cat, ret|
      ret << [cat.name, cat.id]
      ret << cat.children.map { |sub| ["- #{sub.name}", sub.id] }
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!